# Where are the missing tabs in the Sync dialogue?

Tags: git, windows-10, tortoisegit

When opening the `Sync...` dialogue from the context menu, I get the dialogue window with one tab - `Out Commits`.

[image]

However, when looking at the [TortoiseGit online help](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-sync.html), I see the dialogue with 4 tabs, `Log`, `In Commits`, `Ref List`.

[image]

Is this configurable?

Where are my "lost" tabs?

Answer (score 0):

The tabs automatically appear after performing an action OR selecting a local and remote branch. Those are not visible before as those just display specific results.

Comment: Thanks. I have `master` and `master` at the branches drop-down, and `origin` at the `Remote URL:` entry, but only the `Out Commits` is displayed.

Comment: The Ref List is only visible after fetching.

Comment: When `pull`-ing, does not this include `fetch` as well? When looking at the refs in the `.git` folder, I see many of the branches that were pulled (or checked-out, or created) with time. When opening the `Browse References` dialogue from the context menu, I see an almost identical list of refs to the one I see in the file folder. Yet, there is no `Ref list` tab in the `Sync...` dialogue.